# Order by logic for a forum thread

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I have  three columns

```
ThreadID
DateTime
CommentID
ReplyCommentID
```

Query

```
WITH CTE AS ( SELECT CommentID ,
            CommentUserName,
             ReplyCommentID ,
            CommentID AS ThreadID ,
            CAST( CommentID AS VARCHAR( MAX ) ) AS PathStr,
            HtmlComment ,
            CommentPostDocumentID ,
             CommentIsApproved,
            CommentDate 

     FROM Blog_CommentDetails AS T WITH(NOLOCK)
     WHERE ReplyCommentID IS NULL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT T.CommentID ,
            T.CommentUserName,
            T.ReplyCommentID ,
            CTE.ThreadID ,
            PathStr + '-'+ CAST( T.ReplyCommentID AS VARCHAR( MAX ) ) AS PathStr,
            T.HtmlComment ,
            t.CommentPostDocumentID ,
             t.CommentIsApproved,
            T.CommentDate 

     FROM Blog_CommentDetails AS T WITH(NOLOCK)
     JOIN CTE 
     ON T.ReplyCommentID = CTE.CommentID
     WHERE T.ReplyCommentID IS NOT NULL)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE CommentPostDocumentID = 15 AND CommentIsApproved=1
ORDER BY ThreadID, PathStr ,
        CommentDate DESC;
```

I need to order by ThreadID ascending first
Then i need to order by CommentID ascending second
Then i need to order by date descending third
But one condision, when  there is  commenid and replycommendid matches for two rows, rows with commenid should be first.

How can i write  an order by for this?

```
ORDER BY  ThreadID,CommentID,DateTime desc,

IF(ReplyCommentID == CommentID) 
then 
rows with commentid should be first
```

Current result:

[image: actual result]
But the expected result is:

[image: expected result]

Comment: what do you mean by "rows with commentid should be first"? Please add some sample data (preferably DDL + DML) and desired results.

Comment: What do you mean with "rows with commenid should be first"?

Comment: `when there is commenid and replycommendid matches for two rows` ... this implies aggregation.  Please show sample data.

Comment: Also, which columns can be null, and which are `unique`?

Comment: You need aggregation for this, to check the equalty of `CommentID` against `ReplyCommentID` for multiple rows.  Hence, I would guess that your query would need modification, in addition to the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: updated the query

Comment: Could you please provide data in textual form in order to carry out tests? Data representing CTE result would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a calculated value for ordering; However, as calculation requires attributes from separate rows, these rows have first to be combined.
Without demo data in textual form, which I could take over to my environment, it's a bit hard to test.

The following schema is very close to your requirements, if we consider `a` as representing `CommentId` and `b` standing for `ReplyCommentID`:

```
create table test (
    a int,
    b int
    );

insert into test (a,b) values (1,null), (2,1), (3,2), (4,1);

select distinct test.a as a, test.b as b, case when (test.b=test2.a or test.b is null) then 0 else 1 end as priority
from test left join test test2 on test.b = test2.a and test2.b is null
order by priority,a,b
```

Note that the order compared to an `order by a,b` changes analogously to what you expect in your sample data.

Givent that, when applying to your query (after the `WITH CTE...`-part), it should look as follows. As mentioned above, I cannot test it, so please do not throw stones on me if it does not work immediately:

```
SELECT distinct cte.*, case when (cte.ReplyCommentID =cte2.CommentId or cte.ReplyCommentID is null) then 0 else 1 end as priority
FROM CTE left join CTE cte2 on cte.ReplyCommentID = cte2.CommentId and cte2.ReplyCommentID is null
WHERE CommentPostDocumentID = 15 AND CommentIsApproved=1
ORDER BY ThreadID, priority, CommentId, PathStr , CommentDate DESC;
```

[image: Result]

Comment: thanks for the try, but still the query results in the same order, except one more column added called priority

Comment: Made another try, but without data it's really just guessing.

Comment: Now the two rows which are matching is coming in correct order, but entire two rows shifted towards down. It should be in the same place eatlier instead third row should be inserted in between 2 and 3rd

Answer (score 0):

The following extensive example will walk through a tree of comments based on `CommentID` and `ReplyCommentID` (which serves as the `ParentID`). Children of the same `ReplyCommentID` are ordered by `CommentDate DESC`:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    CommentID INT,
    ReplyCommentID INT,
    CommentDate DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
(140,NULL, CAST('20170109' AS DATETIME))
,(141,NULL, CAST('20170110' AS DATETIME))
,(142,141, CAST('20170111' AS DATETIME))
,(143,141, CAST('20170112' AS DATETIME))
,(144,141, CAST('20170113' AS DATETIME))
,(145,144, CAST('20170114' AS DATETIME))
,(146,NULL, CAST('20170115' AS DATETIME));

WITH [Statistics] AS (
    SELECT Records.CommentID, Records.ReplyCommentID
    , COUNT(Children.CommentID) AS NrOfChildren
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Records.ReplyCommentID ORDER BY Records.CommentDate DESC) AS NthChild
    , COUNT(Records.CommentID) OVER (PARTITION BY Records.ReplyCommentID) AS NrOfSiblings
    FROM @Table Records
    LEFT JOIN @Table Children ON Records.CommentID = Children.ReplyCommentID
    GROUP BY Records.CommentID, Records.ReplyCommentID, Records.CommentDate
)

, Tree AS (
    SELECT *
    , 1 AS [Order]
    , 0 AS [Rerouting]
    , CAST(-1 AS INT) AS ReroutedFromNthChild
    FROM [Statistics] AS TreeNode 
    WHERE ReplyCommentID IS NULL AND NthChild = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT NextNode.*
    , TreeNode.[Order] + 1 AS [Order]
    , CASE 
        WHEN (TreeNode.NrOfChildren = 0 AND TreeNode.NthChild = TreeNode.NrOfSiblings AND TreeNode.ReplyCommentID = NextNode.CommentID)
        OR (TreeNode.Rerouting = 1 AND TreeNode.ReroutedFromNthChild = TreeNode.NrOfChildren AND TreeNode.ReplyCommentID = NextNode.CommentID) 
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS [Rerouting]
    , CAST(TreeNode.NthChild AS INT) AS ReroutedFromNthChild
    FROM Tree AS TreeNode
    JOIN [Statistics] AS NextNode 
        --Has children, so select first child
        ON (TreeNode.Rerouting = 0 AND TreeNode.NrOfChildren > 0 AND NextNode.NthChild = 1 AND TreeNode.CommentID = NextNode.ReplyCommentID) 
        --Has no children, so select next sibling
        OR (TreeNode.Rerouting = 0 AND TreeNode.NrOfChildren = 0 AND TreeNode.NthChild + 1 = NextNode.NthChild AND (TreeNode.ReplyCommentID = NextNode.ReplyCommentID OR (TreeNode.ReplyCommentID IS NULL AND NextNode.ReplyCommentID IS NULL)))
        --Has no children or following siblings, so retrace the step (reroute)
        OR (TreeNode.Rerouting = 0 AND TreeNode.NrOfChildren = 0 AND TreeNode.NthChild = TreeNode.NrOfSiblings AND TreeNode.ReplyCommentID = NextNode.CommentID)
        --Was rerouting but has children, so back on track and follow the next child
        OR (TreeNode.Rerouting = 1 AND TreeNode.ReroutedFromNthChild < TreeNode.NrOfChildren AND TreeNode.ReroutedFromNthChild + 1 = NextNode.NthChild AND TreeNode.CommentID = NextNode.ReplyCommentID)
        --Was rerouting and has no other children, so continue rerouting
        OR (TreeNode.Rerouting = 1 AND TreeNode.ReroutedFromNthChild = TreeNode.NrOfChildren AND TreeNode.ReplyCommentID = NextNode.CommentID)
        --Rerouted to the top without children left, jumping to the next sibling
        OR (TreeNode.Rerouting = 1 AND (TreeNode.ReroutedFromNthChild = TreeNode.NrOfChildren OR TreeNode.NrOfChildren = 0) AND TreeNode.NthChild + 1 = NextNode.NthChild AND TreeNode.ReplyCommentID IS NULL AND NextNode.ReplyCommentID IS NULL)
)

select *
from Tree
where Rerouting = 0
ORDER BY [Order]
```

[image: Result]

Comment: this was also my immediate approach; however, `ReplyCommentID` and `CommentID` in question are from different rows.

Comment: I answered it with a join-approach; as I intermediately deleted the answer - can you tell me if the answer is visible to somebody? Thanx

Comment: @StephanLechner I changed my answer

Comment: I have udpated stephens answer , please have a look

Comment: @SmartestVEGA I've edited my answer, previous one didn't take the `CommentDate DESC` into consideration. Also note that this answer refers to your columnnames.

Comment: Thanks for the answer aquillo , the query works with data i given above, but when i added another record with replycommentid which is NULL.  then then result is listing just one row, that too newly added row only getting fltered rest are not showing

Comment: @SmartestVEGA You are right, this query works for a tree with one root, will sligthly change it in order to get it to work with multiple trees.

Comment: @SmartestVEGA Try the current query! Was also able to remove one recursive `CTE`.

Comment: order looks fine but comment id 140 is duplicated :(

Comment: You're right, rather complex logic in the `JOIN` (probably possible to simplify this further). Fixed.